# AVERAGE from AVERAGEIFs that will ignore AVERAGEIFs where is ERROR EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I am trying to calculate AVERAGE from five AverageIFs:

```
AVERAGE(AVERAGEIFs1,AVERAGEIFs2,AVERAGEIFs3,AVERAGEIFs4,AVERAGEIFs5)
```

in AverageIFs2 and AverageIFs4 I am receiving #DIV/0! .
How to calculate AVERAGE from AverageIFs that are not have errors only?

Adding IFERROR, IF(ISERROR) etc before AverageIf is not resolving problem.

Comment: Try placing each `AVERAGEIFS` in a cell with an `IFERROR` like this: `=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(...),"")` then `AVERAGE` the resulting cell values

Comment: On second thoughts this suggestion doesn't seem to work - it might be necessary to do it using some form of sum(...)/count(...)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather tedious, but you might have to do something like this:

```
    =SUM(IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(A1:A2,A1:A2,">"&0),0),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(B1:B2,B1:B2,">"&0),0),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C1:C2,C1:C2,">"&0),0))
/SUM(--ISNUMBER(AVERAGEIFS(A1:A2,A1:A2,">"&0)),--ISNUMBER(AVERAGEIFS(B1:B2,B1:B2,">"&0)),--ISNUMBER(AVERAGEIFS(C1:C2,C1:C2,">"&0)))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

```
=SUM(IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(A1:A2,A1:A2,">"&0),0),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(B1:B2,B1:B2,">"&0),0),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(C1:C2,C1:C2,">"&0),0))
/COUNT(AVERAGEIFS(A1:A2,A1:A2,">"&0),AVERAGEIFS(B1:B2,B1:B2,">"&0),AVERAGEIFS(C1:C2,C1:C2,">"&0))
```

is a bit shorter - Count ignores any #DIV/0!