# Average of Averageifs (ignoring 0 values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set which I am trying to find conditional averages from, I am able to get the results I want using multiple cells, but would like to contain all of the steps in a single cell

I have tried some other solutions on this site (most recently this one: [AVERAGE from AVERAGEIFs that will ignore AVERAGEIFs where is ERROR EXCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219892/average-from-averageifs-that-will-ignore-averageifs-where-is-error-excel)) from similar topics but cannot seem to make any of them work

The three steps I am using are

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($F$3:$F$17,$B$3:$B$17,"TCM",$C$3:$C$17,"Critical"),0)

=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($F$3:$F$17,$B$3:$B$17,"TCM",$C$3:$C$17,"Main"),0)

 =SUM(F23:F24)/COUNTIF(F23:F24,"<>0")
```

The first formula gives a value, the second zero and the third the average of the two, excluding the zero

I would like to know if it is possible to somehow combine these formulas into one cell?

UPDATE

[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xUOZ.png)

In this table i would be looking to get the average of all the "A" in column B that also have "D" and "E" in column C (Using the values in column F to get the average) however in some instances a combination (e.g. "A" and "G") may be zero.  In this instance I want to exclude the zero value from the calculation.

Comment: @TerryW column F is just a list of percentages, columns B and C are a list of groups the item in the row belongs to.  I am unable to Share the exact data  but in this example there are 3 possible entries in each column (i.e. group A, B, C in col B and D, E, F in column c) and

Comment: column F is formulas, B & C are plain text.  There could be any combination of the criteria in each column (i.e AD, AE, AF, BD, BE, etc.)  only used two as i figured i could extrapolate from there.  Some places this formula will be used may have as many as 10 options in column B

Comment: will the formula in column F return blank/empty cell? Is there any relationship between choosing `TCM-Critical` and `TCM-Main`? Are you trying to average the Critical % with the Main % by TCM? You mentioned there could be as many as 10 options in column B, are you averaging column F if all 10 options are met or just averaging only the matched options?

Comment: I have added a sample table to the initial post to try and describe the situation better